# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on <artifact:dependencies> tag

Tags: maven, build, ant

I am trying to invoke ant build using maven and trying to call the below from the ant target

```
<artifact:dependencies pathId="war.lib.path" useScope="runtime">
    <pom file="pom.xml" />
</artifact:dependencies>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <ant antfile="${basedir}/build/build.xml">
                                <target name="build" />
                            </ant>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.settings.RuntimeInfo.<init>(Lorg/apache/maven/settings/Settings;)V

    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.readSettings(AbstractArtifactTask.java:382)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.loadSettings(AbstractArtifactTask.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.initSettings(AbstractArtifactTask.java:278)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.execute(AbstractArtifactTask.java:750)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    ... 66 more
```

Can you let me know what is wrong
Edit 1:
The. Maven Version  used is 3.1.1 and tried with  ant plugin 1.8 and 3.0.0 still getting the same error.
here is the plugin used in pom.xml

Comment: Show your POM. Do you use the antrun plugin?

Comment: Could you please add the following information to the question: 1. Version of Maven --- 2. Version of maven-antrun-plugin --- 3. What XML schema declares <artifact:dependencies> element?

Comment: Yes I am Using <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>

Comment: version of maven is Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 20:52:22+0530)

Comment: I am using it inside one of ant targets.. running ant build runs perfectly fine.. why it is not running inside maven here is the targert <target name="ui-war-build-with-no-help">
  <property file="../ui/etc/verstamp.ini" />
  <tstamp />
  <!-- retrieve depending libraries -->
  <artifact:dependencies pathId="war.lib.path" useScope="runtime">
   <pom file="pom.xml" />
  </artifact:dependencies>

Comment: @JFabianMeier : updated the question. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: @IllyaKysil : added the information as asked.Kindly help

Comment: I guess you are using some ant methods that need to be added as additional dependency in the antrun plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/dependencies.html) task from the [Maven Ant Tasks component](https://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/), which is **retired and no longer maintained** since at least May of 2014.

You should either downgrade the version of Maven, which I assume is version 2 based on the date of the last update of the component.

Or migrate your Ant build scripts to the [Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks](https://maven.apache.org/resolver-ant-tasks/) , as recommended at [Maven Ant Tasks](https://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/).

Comment: I cannot downgrade the version and <resolve>
    <dependencies pomRef="pom"/>
    <remoterepos refid="all"/>
    <path refid="war.lib.path" classpath="compile"/>
    <path refid="war.lib.path" classpath="test"/>
</resolve>  is also not avle to resolve the same - @Illya Kysil

Comment: How to write <artifact:dependencies pathId="war.lib.path" useScope="runtime">
   <pom file="pom.xml" />

  </artifact:dependencies> using maven ant task componenet

Comment: Did you check linked Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks page? There is an example of the task which is similar to what you've described in the question. Please raise a separate question if explanation there is not enough. For the moment, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve with the combination of Maven's pom.xml and Ant's build.xml. If you just need to copy the dependencies of the POM to some folder - check maven-dependency-plugin. That plugin may completely replace the need for Ant.

Comment: Thanks  Illya Kysil . I will raise a seperate question for that